# how to convert column of object datatype to int64 datatype in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

I merged two tables and hence a column has a `dtype` object, I need to convert it to `int`, where I am getting a type error.

I used `astype` function, but the object is not converted to `string`, getting the following type error:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a
>   number, not 'method'

Comment: `df['col_name'].astype(int)` and not `df['col_name'].astype(int())`

Comment: Used above piece of code, still same error

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your dataframe you have some NaN values, Check that first with

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

Then fill the NaN values or drop them, and after that you can you convert your values.

if it's not the problem, can you try something like that :

```
df['col']=df['col'].apply(lambda x : int(x))
```

Comment: no null values, I have checked and filled those values

Comment: I tried above piece of code, to_numeric but nothing is helpful